# Chrome: Borders missing on table when cell is hidden

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a standard HTML table with some borders that appear in most browsers, like Firefox, but in Chrome when one of the cell is hidden, the borders disappear. The cells are being set to display: none, the borders are not on the tds but on both the tr and table elements. Regardless, Chrome treats it like it doesn't exist and just skips over it. Is there any -webkit- specific stuff I can use to fix this problem? I've tried applying the border to basically any element I could but so far have not had any luck. Anyone else ever experienced this?

CSS:

```css
.hide-dm, .hidden, .hide-training, table.hide-dm, table.hide-training, .hide-ca {
 display: none;
}

.table {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table > tbody > tr {
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td.border-bottom, .table > tbody > tr > td.border-bottom, tr.border-bottom {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}

tr.hide-training + tr.backup_border, tr.hidden + tr.backup_border, tr.hide-dm + tr.backup_border {
 border-top: 3px solid #000;
}
 
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td.border-left, .table > tbody > tr > td.border-left, .table-bordered > thead > tr > th.border-left {
  border-left: 3px solid #000;
}

.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td.border-right, .table > tbody > tr > td.border-right {
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="text-center active" colspan="3">Current</th>
   <th class="text-center border-left" colspan="3">New</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="border-bottom">
         <td class="active" colspan="3">
             <div class="manager-header manager-header-current manager-header-print form-horizontal col-sm-3">
                 <span id="current_selector_label" class="text-bold">Store:</span>
     <span id="current-store-parent">240</span>
             </div>

          <div class="manager-header manager-header-current manager-header-print col-sm-3">
           <strong>Role:</strong>
           <span id="old_role_label">DM</span>
          </div>               

          <div class="manager-header manager-header-print col-sm-6">
           <strong>Manager:</strong>
              <span class="mgr-header-name" id="current-mgr-header-name">
               Rob Tufts (184101)
              </span>
            </div>
         </td>
      <td class="border-left" colspan="3">
             <div class="form-horizontal d-inline-block align-middle manager-header manager-header-print" style="width: 28%;">
                 <label id="new_selector_label" for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Store</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div id="new-store-parent">
                      <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft form-control text-center dm-hidden dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_newLocationNumber" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="newLocationNumber" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation" style="display: none;"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" id="newLocationNumber" maxlength="4" tabindex="6" data-original="2569" aria-required="true" placeholder="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="store" value="2569" type="hidden"></div></div>
       <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center hidden" id="widget_newDistrictSearch" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="newDistrictSearch" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation" style="display: none;"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" tabindex="0" id="newDistrictSearch" maxlength="4" data-original="2569" aria-required="false" placeholder="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="district" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
               </div>
                 </div>
             </div>

          <div class="manager-header manager-header-print d-inline-block align-middle form-horizontal" style="width: 25%;">
           <label class="control-label" style="padding-right: 3px;">Role</label>
             <table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitDownArrowButton form-control width-forty text-center dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" data-value="SMIT" data-original="SMIT" id="manager_role" widgetid="manager_role" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lang="en"><tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" aria-selected="true" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">SMIT</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><input name="role" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="SMIT" aria-hidden="true" type="hidden"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table>
          </div>

          <div class="manager-header manager-header-print d-inline-block align-middle" style="width: 45%;">
           <strong>Manager:</strong>
             <span class="mgr-header-name" id="new-mgr-header-name">
              Rob Tufts (184101)
             </span>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="active text-center border-bottom" colspan="3">
    <div class="manager-header col-sm-6 current-adjust  hide-dm">
     <div><strong>Sales %</strong></div>
     <span class="" id="mgr-sales-percent-current">0.00%</span>
    </div>
    <div class="manager-header col-sm-6 current-adjust ">
     <div><strong>ICP %</strong></div>
     <span class="" id="mgr-icp-percent-current">1.00%</span>
    </div>
    <div id="current_hourly_rate_wrapper" class="col-sm-6 hidden  current-adjust hide-dm">
     <div><strong>Hourly Rate</strong></div>
     <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset decimal-value" id="widget_current_hourly_rate" role="presentation" widgetid="current_hourly_rate" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" data-value="" id="current_hourly_rate" size="9" data-original="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="current_hourly_rate" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 current-adjust hidden">
     <div><strong>Alt Rate</strong></div>
     <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset decimal-value" id="widget_current_alt_rate" role="presentation" widgetid="current_alt_rate" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" data-value="" id="current_alt_rate" size="9" data-original="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="oldAltRate" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center border-left border-bottom" colspan="3">
    <div id="new_sales_percent_wrapper" class="manager-header col-sm-6 new-adjust  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden">
     <div><strong>Sales %</strong></div>
     <table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox dijitDownArrowButton form-control width-two-third text-center dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" data-value="1.00" data-original="1.00" id="mgr-sales-percent-new" widgetid="mgr-sales-percent-new" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lang="en"><tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" aria-selected="true" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">1.00%</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><input name="salesIncentivePercent" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="1.00" aria-hidden="true" type="hidden"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table>
           <div id="read-mgr-sales-percent-new"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="new_icp_percent_wrapper" class="manager-header col-sm-6 new-adjust hide-training training-hidden">
     <div id="manager_new_icp_label"><strong>ICP %</strong></div>
     <table class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitSelect dijitValidationTextBox dijitDownArrowButton form-control width-two-third text-center hide-training training-hidden hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode,tableNode,focusNode,_popupStateNode" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" data-original="1.00" data-value="1.00" id="mgr-icp-percent-new" widgetid="mgr-icp-percent-new" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" lang="en"><tbody role="presentation"><tr role="presentation"><td class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" role="presentation"><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" role="presentation"><span role="option" aria-selected="true" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitSelectLabel dijitValidationTextBoxLabel ">1.00%</span></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><input name="icpIncentivePercent" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" value="1.00" aria-hidden="true" type="hidden"></td><td class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></td></tr></tbody></table>
           <div id="read-mgr-icp-percent-new">
            1.00%
           </div>
    </div>
    <div id="new_hourly_rate_wrapper" class="col-sm-3 hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new new-adjust  dm-hidden">
     <div><strong>Hourly Rate</strong></div>
     <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new dm-hidden decimal-value" id="widget_new_hourly_rate" role="presentation" widgetid="new_hourly_rate" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="7" id="new_hourly_rate" size="9" data-original="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="new_hourly_rate" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="text-center col-sm-2 active border-bottom"></td>
   <td class="text-center active border-bottom col-sm-2"><strong>Monthly</strong></td>
   <td class="text-center active border-bottom col-sm-2"><strong>Yearly</strong></td>
   <td class="text-center col-sm-2 border-bottom border-left"></td>
   <td class="text-center border-bottom col-sm-2"><strong>Monthly</strong></td>
   <td class="text-center border-bottom col-sm-2"><strong>Yearly</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
   <td class="active width-cell-label">Base Salary</td>
   <td class="text-center active" id="current_salary_month" data-value="833.3333333333334">$833.33</td>
   <td class="text-center active decimal-value" data-original="10,000" id="current_salary_year" data-value="10000">$10,000.00</td>
   <td class="border-left width-cell-label">Base Salary</td>
   <td class="text-center">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft form-control text-center center-block width-reset decimal-value dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_new_salary_month" role="presentation" widgetid="new_salary_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="8" id="new_salary_month" size="9" aria-required="true" data-value="1966.67" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="new_salary_month" value="1966.67" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new" data-original="23,600.04" id="new_salary_year" data-value="23600.04">$23,600.04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="active width-cell-label">Sales</td>
   <td class="text-center active " id="current_sales_month" data-value="">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset" id="widget_current_sales_month" role="presentation" widgetid="current_sales_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" id="current_sales_month" size="9" aria-required="true" data-original="208,754" value="208,754" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="oldMonthlySales" value="208754" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field border-right " id="current_sales_year" data-value="2505048">$2,505,048</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hide-training training-hidden">Sales</td>
   <td class="text-center hide-training training-hidden">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset" id="widget_new_sales_month" role="presentation" widgetid="new_sales_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="9" id="new_sales_month" size="9" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="monthlySales" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hide-training training-hidden" id="new_sales_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="width-cell-label active">ICP %</td>
   <td class="text-center active ">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset decimal-value" id="widget_current_icp_month" role="presentation" widgetid="current_icp_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="4" id="current_icp_month" size="9" aria-required="true" data-value="25.11" data-original="25.11" value="25.11" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="oldIcpPercent" value="25.11" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field border-right " id="current_icp_year"></td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hide-training training-hidden">ICP %</td>
   <td class="text-center hide-training training-hidden">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset decimal-value hide-training training-hidden" id="widget_new_icp_month" role="presentation" widgetid="new_icp_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="10" id="new_icp_month" size="9" data-value="" data-original="" value="" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="icpPercent" value="" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center hide-training training-hidden" id="new_icp_year"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
   <td class="width-cell-label active border-bottom">Incentive Threshold</td>
   <td class="text-center active border-bottom updated_field  " id="current_incentive_month"></td>
   <td class="text-center active border-bottom updated_field border-right  " id="current_incentive_year"></td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-bottom border-left hide-training training-hidden">Incentive Threshold</td>
   <td class="text-center border-bottom hide-training training-hidden">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitNumberTextBox dijitValidationTextBox form-control text-center center-block width-reset" id="widget_new_incentive_month" role="presentation" widgetid="new_incentive_month" lang="en"><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation" type="text"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" tabindex="11" id="new_incentive_month" size="9" data-value="0" value="0" aria-invalid="false" type="text"><input name="incentiveThreshold" value="0" type="hidden"></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="text-center border-bottom hide-training training-hidden" id="new_incentive_year"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=" hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new">
   <td class="width-cell-label active ot_title_cell" id="current_ot_title" colspan="3">
    
   </td>
   <td class="active text-center hidden hide-dm updated_field" id="current_ot_month"></td>
   <td class="active text-center hidden hide-dm updated_field border-right" id="current_ot_year">-</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden">Overtime (8 hr/week)</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden" id="new_ot_month"></td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden" id="new_ot_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="  hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new">
   <td id="current_ot_premium_title" class="width-cell-label active ot_title_cell" colspan="3">
    
   </td>
   <td class="active text-center hidden hide-dm  updated_field" id="current_ot_premium_month"></td>
   <td class="active text-center hidden hide-dm  updated_field border-right" id="current_ot_premium_year">-</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden">OT Premium</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden" id="new_ot_premium_month"></td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hidden ca-hidden ca-hidden-new  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden" id="new_ot_premium_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="backup_border  ">
   <td class="width-cell-label active" colspan="3">
    
   </td>    
   <td class="text-center active updated_field hide-dm " id="current_sales_incentive_month">$0</td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field border-right hide-dm " id="current_sales_incentive_year">-</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden">Sales Incentive</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden" id="new_sales_incentive_month">$1,451</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new  dm-hidden hide-training training-hidden" id="new_sales_incentive_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
   <td class="width-cell-label active">ICP Incentive</td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field " id="current_icp_incentive_month" data-value="524.181294">$524</td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field border-right " id="current_icp_incentive_year" data-value="6290.175528">$6,290</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hide-training training-hidden">ICP Incentive</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hide-training training-hidden" id="new_icp_incentive_month">$0</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hide-training training-hidden" id="new_icp_incentive_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=" hidden">
   <td class="width-cell-label active">Incentive Offset</td>
   <td class="text-center active ca-hidden hidden  updated_field " id="current_incentive_offset_month">
    $0
   </td>
   <td class="text-center active ca-hidden hidden  updated_field" id="current_incentive_offset_year">
    $0
   </td>
   <td class="border-left" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
   <td class="active width-cell-label">Total Incentive</td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field" id="current_total_incentive_month" data-value="524.181294">$524</td>
   <td class="text-center active updated_field border-right" id="current_total_incentive_year" data-value="6290.175528">$6,290</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-left hide-training training-hidden">Total Incentive</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hide-training training-hidden" id="new_total_incentive_month">$0</td>
   <td class="text-center updated_field updated_field_new hide-training training-hidden" id="new_total_incentive_year">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-bottom active">Three Check Compensation</td>
   <td class="border-bottom active " id="current_three_check_month"></td>
   <td class="border-bottom active text-center updated_field " id="current_three_check_year" data-value="419.3450352">$419</td>
   <td class="width-cell-label border-bottom border-left">Three Check Compensation</td>
   <td class="border-bottom text-center" id="new_three_check_month"></td>
   <td class="border-bottom text-center updated_field updated_field_new" id="new_three_check_year" data-value="1200">$1,200</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Borders Visible in Firefox]

[image: Borders Missing in Chrome]

Comment: Could you post a little bit of the html for the table so we can try it?

Comment: Yea, it will be nice to see your html and also how you make your cells hidden

Comment: Added the HTML for the table. The cells are made hidden by adding classes based on some JS. All of the classes that are added just set display: none on the td and that's it.

Comment: I've pasted this into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn97thL1/), but I'm having difficulty seeing any difference between Chrome and Firefox. Which cell borders are giving you problems?

Comment: Sorry about that, there was some important styles missing. I updated the fiddle and it should better reflect my issue now.

Comment: Border-styles are set on the cells, so if you hide the cells or entire rows this style should (obviously) not be visible anymore. So what you can do is only hide the contents of cells. Setting `display:none` will remove an element from the document flow, in tables that seems to me a good reason for a table to break.

Comment: Try using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

Comment: I realize that display: none takes the element out of the document flow but, to me, that shouldn't have an adverse effect on the tr. From the standpoint of it's overall size, the width of the tr isn't changed because some of the tds are hidden. You can even look in DevTools and see it still at 100% of table width. So to me, it makes sense that a border would stretch that distance and be visible regardless of the state of the content within it. And all of this doubly applies for the table element. There should be no scenario where a border is allowed to "jump" like in my screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to put your CSS hidden classes on the table cell contents instead of the cells themselves, on a wrapper element.

```
<td><div class="hidden">...</div></td>
```

Or if you can guarantee that the table cells will have only elements inside them (no plain text nodes), you can do something like this:

```
.hidden:not(td), td.hidden * {
  display: none;
}
```

Or if you don't mind using JavaScript, you could write some JavaScript to go through all table cells with your class defined on them, create wrapper divs on the fly with the hidden class, and remove the hidden class from the table cell.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

$("td.hidden").removeClass("hidden").wrapInner("<div class='hidden'></div>");
```